# C++ builder 10.4 FMX TBluetoothLE Read Device Value Exception Error

Tags: c++, firemonkey

I use C++ builder 10.4 design my project,my project need keep bluetooth Connect and receive bluetooth value,question is when i get value form TBluetoothGattCharacteristic my app will crash,

i try as below

```
void __fastcall TForm2::BluetoothLE1CharacteristicRead(TObject * const Sender,
TBluetoothGattCharacteristic * const ACharacteristic,TBluetoothGattStatus AGattStatus)
{
    TBytes t_bata = const_cast<TBluetoothGattCharacteristic*>(ACharacteristic)->Value; 
   
    Do My Code.....

}
```

[1.Exception Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgvpn.jpg)

[2.Press Break Stop Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSSek.jpg)

Comment: You should mentation that your platform is Android. Do you have added the required permission for using Bluetooth to your project?

Comment: Yes I already add permission  for Bluetooth